# How to get rid of extra margins created by CSS scale

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe that shows an external website, but that website is extremely large and I want to scale it down so that it fits ion the iframe. Currently, I am using the css scale property, however that generates a large margin around the picture.  Any ideas on how to change that?

CODE:

```
<iframe src="../libraries/javascript/slideshow/index.php?show=build_season_2014" height="1100" width="2100" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframe>
```

Comment: `-moz-transform-scale(0.5);` isn’t a thing. Just use `transform: scale(0.5);` now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need to add the following to the iframe's style:

```css
-webkit-transform-origin: left top;
-moz-transform-origin: left top;
```

Comment: That solves the spacing issue, but it still has the space around the iframe.